# jquery selector help. Everything but the specified selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following function to open an overlay menu:

```
   $('.context-switch').click(function() {
       $(".context-switch-menu").toggle();
   });
```

To hide the menu, I would like the user to be able to click on any area outside ".context-switch-menu"

I am trying with :not() but with no success..

Answer (score 1):

The reason this can be difficult is because of event bubbling.

You can try something like this:

```
$('.context-switch').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(".context-switch-menu").toggle();
});

$(".context-switch-menu").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});


$("body").click(function(e){
     $(".context-switch-menu").hide();
});
```

The `e.stopPropagation()` prevents the `click` event from bubbling to the `body` handlers. Without it, any click to `.context-switch` or `.context-switch-menu` would also trigger the body event handler, which you don't want, as it would nullify the effect of the `.context-switch` click half the time. (ie, if the state is hidden, and then you click to show, the event would bubble and trigger the `body` handler that would then hide the `.context-switch-menu` again.)

Comment: This will close the contextmenu before the event of the element inside the contextmenu happened.

Comment: I think you would want the `stopPropagation` on `.context-switch-menu` actually.  Or in addition?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
     if ($(e.target).hasClass('context-switch')) {
         return;
     }

     $(".context-switch-menu").hide();
});

$('.context-switch').click(function() {
    $(".context-switch-menu").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yep, event bubbling let's you catch the event at the top, assuming none of the other elements on the page kill bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

try this, we don't want to call a function when you clicked on the element itself, and not when we click inside the element. That's why we need 2 checks.

You want to use `e.target` which is the element you clicked.

```
$("html").click(function(e){
    if( !$(e.target).is(".context-switch-menu") && 
        $(e.target).closest(".context-switch-menu").length == 0
    )
    {
       alert("CLICKED OUTSIDE");
    }
});
```

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xc25K/1/

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, would something like this work?:

```
$('.context-switch').click(function() {
       $(".context-switch-menu").show();
   });
$(document).click(function() {
       $(".context-switch-menu").hide();
   });
```

Instead of using `document`, `'html'` or `'body'` may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className !='context-switch-menu') {
        $(".context-switch-menu").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea here, based on what what others have suggested in the past:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    //this should give you the clicked element's id attribute
    var elem = $(e.target).attr('classname'); 
    if(elem !== 'context-switch-menu'){
        $('.context-switch-menu').slideUp('slow'); 
        //or however you want to hide it
    }
});
```